# best online tutorials for J2EE and J2ME

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, frameworks, java-me

I am very new to J2EE and J2ME but I am familiar with core java.
Now I have started learning J2EE and J2ME.
I request you all to suggest the best online tutorials both (pdf and videos) for J2EE and J2ME.
Also please guide me How to start learning the MVC Frame works,which should start first and which is the best?

Thank you

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Quora it

J2EE - https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-and-quickest-way-to-learn-J2EE

J2ME - https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-learn-J2ME-from-basic

even you can find better articles.